# CSS Drop Shadow on Body

Tags: html, css, styling

I have a layout build by chopping and changing several themes together. On that layout there is a shadow behind all the content which is triggered with this CSS:

```
body {
-webkit-box-shadow:0px 5px 10px #1c1c1c;
-moz-box-shadow:0px 5px 10px #1c1c1c;
box-shadow:0px 5px 10px #1c1c1c;
}
```

So now i am rebuilding the theme myself so i can structure the div's and the css the way I want it. The original design had a header which just had its text aligned to the right. For the rebuild i made a 3 column layout for the header so i can add a photo to the left side and some content in the center.

Im not able to use the above shadow code in my new layout. It doesn't drop a shadow around the content for me. Instead if i take the below code and drop it into each Div ID's CSS for each of the 3 columns it will drop a shadow... however the shadow spills over into the second column and into the third column

```
-webkit-box-shadow:0px 5px 10px #1c1c1c;
-moz-box-shadow:0px 5px 10px #1c1c1c;
box-shadow:0px 5px 10px #1c1c1c;
```

Now im not great with HTML & CSS but im trying my best. I tried to put the 3 cols into a DIV and drop the shadow onto that div but it still didn't work. I tried butting the cols into where the *** symbols are in the code below

```
 <div id="blah">**************</div>
```

Anyone any suggestions on what im missing?

Comment: Do you have an html example we can see? Drop shadows are outside of elements and can push into other elements if things aren't given enough space. At least try giving the inner divs some margins and seeing if that works, but it's hard to know what's wrong without seeing the html

Comment: What is it specifically you are trying to achieve again? It seems like you want an overall drop shadow for all your content, but you don't want it "spilling over"... not sure what you mean by that either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying the drop shadow to the outside div is the right idea but if you are using divs to make the inner columns you need to apply a clearfix to the last element.

```
<div id="blah">
   <div class="third">First</div>
   <div class="third">Second</div>
   <div class="third">Third</div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

with the css

```
.clear { clear:both; }
```

Is this the effect you were looking for?
http://jsfiddle.net/LcBUX/3/

Comment: That has worked perfectly for me. Thank You!

[LINK](http://music.insanitypop.com/test.html)